# Do Kotlin classes that inherit from Java classes also inherit from Any?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

Do Kotlin classes that inherit from Java classes also inherit from Any?

If we have a Java class Foo, and a Kotlin class Bar that inherits from Foo, and we're trying to use it in a MutableList in Kotlin, then should the following work?

```
class Class(items: MutableList<Bar> = mutableListOf()) {
    var items: MutableList<Any> = items
}
```

Comment: Me not knowing much about Kotlin yet, but knowing that Java is generically *invariant* when it comes to this, was shocked to learn that this *should* be possible, if I read [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c470) correctly.  I'm not confident in this finding enough to list it as an answer, but this'll at least give you a great lead to go off of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. `Any` is a [mapped type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) that corresponds to `java.lang.Object` (which is the supertype for all Java classes), so, basically, every Java class is seen from Kotlin as a subtype of `Any`. The `something is Any` check is always true for both Kotlin and Java types, as long as `something` is non-null.

Actually, `Any` is *represented by* `java.lang.Object` on the JVM platform:

```
println(Any::class.qualifiedName) // kotlin.Any
println(Any::class.jvmName)       // java.lang.Object
```